# Entity Framework Data Annotations and multilanguage

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4, globalization

I have this code for my entities.

I wonder if there is a way to replace the hard coded text with some reference to resource files depending on the language selected by the user.

```
public class Applicant
    {
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int ApplicantID { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Name is required")]
        [StringLength(20, MinimumLength = 3, ErrorMessage = "Name should not be longer than 20 characters.")]
        [Display(Name = "First and LastName")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are talking about Localization.Check this

http://adamyan.blogspot.com/2010/02/aspnet-mvc-2-localization-complete.html

```
 [Display(Name = "Email", ResourceType = typeof(Localization))]
 [Required(ErrorMessageResourceName = "Required", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Localization))]
 [Email(ErrorMessageResourceName = "EmailFormatError", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Localization))]
 public string Email { get; set; }
```

Comment: I love the example, but I am not doing mvc, just webforms, does it change anything?